# Gulp why single filetype is not working in brackets

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

In my `gulpfile`, I've noticed this weird behavior. If I have my watch defined like this (with bracket):

```
gulp.watch([`${dirBase}/source/scss/**/*.{scss}`],() => {
  gulpBase.start('scss');
});
```

==> When I change any scss file, it doesn't detect any changes and won't run task.

When I change into this:

```
gulp.watch([`${dirBase}/source/scss/**/*.scss`],() => {
  gulpBase.start('scss');
});
```

This one works.

The same applies for `.{js}` and `.js`, any idea why ?

P.s: I'm using gulp 3.9.1 (actually it was a project from the client and I chose not to upgrade at this phase)

Answer (score 0):

You are using javascript template strings. If you dirBase='/home/xyz/code'

Then `${dirBase}/source/scss/**/*.{scss}` will result in

'/home/xyz/code/source/scss/**/*.{scss}'

whereas `${dirBase}/source/scss/**/*.scss`

will result in '/home/xyz/code/source/scss/**/*.scss'.

Hence your second piece of code is working.

Comment: the original piece of code was like this `[`${dirBase}/source/**/*.{scss,js,jsx}`]` then it just call `.start('build')`, I'm in the process of splitting those into minor ones but not sure why it doesn't work (even when it was using with js template string at first)